# How to map a stream that flows through a paddy field without a proper channel

Tags: openstreetmap, network, mapping, quickosm, stream

I'm mapping a stream in Kerala (India) and found out that a stream flows onto a paddy field and flows through it. At the end of the field it again becomes a proper stream. How can I map it in the OpenStreetMap?

Comment: Please ask the OSM community directly: https://community.openstreetmap.org.
https://gis.stackexchange.com is not a proper platform to ask "How to map"-questions.